# Android: create a dialog with transparent background, no border and shade

Tags: android, dialog

I want to create a dialog with transparent BG and no border.
For this I use android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar.

But in the dialog I have UI componenets - imageview and edittext.

I want these to create a shade over the activity page. Like the regular dialog is doing.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you'll create a custom dialog, this link shows you how to do this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Well. That is exactly what I am doing. A new dialg with the theme:Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar. But this creates the dialog with no BG and images are just drawn over the activity with no shades. Maybe can manually add shade to imageview and edittext?